# IDXGIFactory2::CreateSwapChainForHwnd fails

Tags: directx, directx-11, direct3d, direct3d11, dxgi

https://1drv.ms/u/s!AkVRV9eGJ20rgTu13uTcNkhp0eZb?e=lwMe70

That links takes you to my OneDrive where you can download my Visual Studio 2022 solution and project (it is a .7z file of 17.7KB), it only has code to display a win32 window and little more. I also included an image that tells you my DirectX specs that the DirectX Diagnostic Tool reports. The image is the following image:

[image: My DirectX specs]

The problem is what the title says, I would like you to see if you can compile it without problems, I am afraid that it may be failing because I can't use Direct3D 11.1 (is Direct3D 11.1 a requirement? I can't find information about it), but then I tried creating the D3D device with the D3D11_CREATE_DEVICE_PREVENT_ALTERING_LAYER_SETTINGS_FROM_REGISTRY creation flag (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/d3d11/ne-d3d11-d3d11_create_device_flag) just to test if I can use Direct3D 11.1 (because that flag is not supported until Direct3D 11.1) and the creation succeeded... so I don't know anymore...

Comment: @PaulSanders Of course it returns non-zero, it returns 0x887A0001 (DXGI_ERROR_INVALID_CALL). You clearly haven't even seen the code. And why do you assume that I haven't put effort in trying to understand what is happening?

Comment: When you program with DirectX make sure you enable the "debug layer" in dev. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3d11/using-the-debug-layer-to-test-apps and https://walbourn.github.io/direct3d-sdk-debug-layer-tricks/. This will show you why it fails: *"Alpha blended swapchains must be created with CreateSwapChainForComposition, or CreateSwapChainForCoreWindow with the DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_FLAG_FOREGROUND_LAYER flag."*

Comment: @zeleska You're right, I apologize, comment deleted.

Comment: @SimonMourier Thank you! And you know, I did read "Using the debug layer to debug apps" before posting this question, and I did activate it with the flag, but I thought that "debug output" meant "throwing exceptions", so I was lost when the debugger was not throwing anything, until a little ago that I came to know what it really is, oh my god..., Again, thank you, if you post your comment as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: May be you can get the return result and get the error information by FormatMessageW()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you program with DirectX make sure you *always* enable the "debug layer" in dev and check the output in Visual Studio's "Output" window (or other debugger output).

Check these links: [Using the debug layer to debug apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3d11/using-the-debug-layer-to-test-apps) and [Direct3D SDK Debug Layer Tricks](https://walbourn.github.io/direct3d-sdk-debug-layer-tricks/) for more on this as the way it can be installed has changed over DirectX version and years...

This will show you why it fails:

> Alpha blended swapchains must be created with
> CreateSwapChainForComposition, or CreateSwapChainForCoreWindow with
> the DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_FLAG_FOREGROUND_LAYER flag.